# Odoo advanced search on store=False calulated fields

Tags: odoo-8

I have a calculated field with a store=False attribute.

```
total_achievment = fields.Float(string='Achieved %', store= False, readonly=True,
                                 compute='_compute_achievment', default=0)
```

It works well, it displays fine the required values, but it does not appear in the field list of the advanced search panel.

My question is: How can I do searches based on the total_achievment field such as Achieved % greater than 80?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware, you cannot do advanced searches on computed, non stored fields. If you do not have a huge dependency chain, you should just set store = True. It would perform very poorly if you are trying to do large searches on fields that are computed on the fly anyways.